Multiple construction and destruction of static variable in multiple translation units
In C++11 code I have a static variable with a nontrivial constructor and destructor (which allocates memory):
// in logger.h
class logger {
public:
    class log_data
    {
        // log_data allocates and frees memory during construction/destruction
    }

    static log_data l;
};

// in logger.cpp
logger::log_data logger::l;

logger.cpp is then compiled into both a shared library and an executable which links to the shared library itself. I expect the linker to recognize that logger::l is compiled twice and "merge" the two copies.
The problem is that, at runtime, this is what I think is happening:

The executable initializes logger::l on a given memory address, before main() is called, by calling the constructor
The library does the same, on the same memory address, overwriting it
main() is normally executed
The library deletes the object
The executable deletes the object at the same address

I am pretty sure that's the case because:

on x86, valgrind detects that a block of memory in log_data constructor has been allocated and it is definitely lost at program exit (which makes sense since the first initialization is overwritten by the second). For some reason, it does not complain about double destruction at program exit
on armv7, the program segfaults after main() is completed after printing "double free or corruption (fasttop)". I do not have valgrind available on that platform to double check the allocation, but gdb reports a corrupt stack after main exits.

My question is: is there a way to tell the compiler that a static variable has to be constructed and destructed only once, no matter in how many libraries or executable is compiled? Are there any other solutions?
I tried removing logger.cpp from the executable compilation, and linking it with only 1 shared library which includes logger.cpp. It properly works, but the problem remains because logger.cpp can be included in multiple shared libraries, all used by the same executable
Thank you

Should i prefer using inline static member variables?

"logger.cpp is then compiled into both a shared library and an executable which links to the shared library itself.": That's an ODR violation. The definition must exist in only one of the two. Why do you compile the same .cpp file into both a library and the executable? That's almost guaranteed to go wrong.

Short answer:  no.   From a standard perspective (not withstanding the fact that libraries are not mentioned by the standard) your breaking the one-definition rule.  The result you're seeing would be the same if you #included logger.cpp directly in two distinct source files of your project.   The way around such things is to build/load your libraries in a way that avoids there being multiple definitions.  One option is to place your logger functionality into a separate shared library that is dynamically loaded by all executables and other shared libraries that need it.

Using inline works in the sense that on x86 I am not getting the valgrind error. Would it also be standard compliant? By the way, I cannot do this on armv7 since I have an old toolchain with gcc4.9, which does not support C++-17 (which introduced inline variables)
Probably on arm the best solution is the one Peter mentioned: compiling one logging library to be shared among the other components
Thank you!

Avoid static global variablesm too much can go wrong with them. What you can do is have one header file with a meyer's singleton, a function that looks like this. inline logger& get_logger() { static logger log; return log; }. But better designs using dependency injection (to various degrees0 exist, because in general, just avoid globals and singletons in the first place.

Is your app multithreaded?

It is, but I was able to reproduce the issue even with just 1 thread, so I don't think it's related

Both the executable and shared libraries will get their own logger::log_data logger::l; static variable. You can confirm this with a tool like nm.
I've set up a basic local reproduction with the following:
// foo.hpp
void foo();

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

void foo() {}

// log.hpp
#include <iostream>

class logger {
public:
    logger() {
        std::cout<<"logger()"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~logger() {
        std::cout<<"~logger()"<<std::endl;
    }
    void log() {}
};

extern logger logger_global;

// log.cpp
#include "log.hpp"

logger logger_global;

// log_internal.cpp
#include "log.hpp"

void logger::log() {}

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "log.hpp"
#include "foo.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout<<"main "<<std::endl;
    logger_global.log();
    foo();
}

// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(test LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_library(foo SHARED log.cpp foo.cpp)

add_executable(exec main.cpp log.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exec PUBLIC foo)

Running the executable:
$ ./exec
logger()
logger()
main 
~logger()
~logger()

Looking at nm:
$ nm exec | grep logger_global
0000000000001244 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_logger_global
0000000000004151 B logger_global
$ nm libfoo.so | grep logger_global
0000000000004031 B logger_global

Both the executable and the library get their own logger_global and each does its own static construction and destruction. Unlike a static library, the linker can't grab only what is needed from the shared library. The entire shared library must be loaded into memory and as part of that its static data must be initialized. Running in a debugger, you can verify that logger::logger is called twice with the same this pointer.
You may wonder what _GLOBAL__sub_I_logger_global is and why only the executable has it. This function is automatically generated by the compiler and performs static initialization for the global logger. The shared library actually has one too, but, it has a different name: _GLOBAL__sub_I_log.cpp.
What to do?
You should pull the common logger code out into its own library and have both your library and executable link the logger library.

It looks like I am also be able to solve the issue with a singleton
log_data& get_log_data() {
    static log_data instance;
    return instance;
}

That way I don't have to declare anything in logger.cpp, and it looks cleaner, as I don't have to create a library just for a few lines of code.
Does this make sense as well?
Thank you

A  log_data& get_log_data() { static log_data instance; return instance; } that is compiled into both will be bad for similar ODR reasons

Could you please elaborate on that? I thought that such a function would be considered "inline", and that you can have multiple definitions of the same inline function, provided that they are identical. Thank you

For the double destruction, Valgrind memcheck doesn’t care about destructors. It redirects all allocation and deallocation functions (malloc family and operators new and delete), instruments all memory reads and writes and also wraps all system calls. Of course if multiple calls to a destructor lead to multiple deletes of the same memory then errors will be reported.
